# Change EditText according to another EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I'm new to Android development. I have two EditTexts, and I'm trying to change value of ET1 according to ET2, and also value of ET2 according to ET1, automatically during the typing.

Sum of their values must be 200. So if I want to type 56 in ET1, when I type 5, ET2 should display 195. When I add 6, ET2 should display 144 (200 - 56). Everything should happen while focus is still on ET1.

```
scoreWe.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (v.hasFocus()) {
                scoreYou.addTextChangedListener(null);
                scoreWe.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        int scoreW;
                        try {
                            scoreW = Integer.parseInt(scoreWe.getText().toString());
                        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                            scoreW = 0;
                        }
                        int scoreY = 200 - scoreW;
                        String scY = Integer.toString(scoreY);
                        scoreYou.setText(scY);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

-

```
scoreYou.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (v.hasFocus()) {
                scoreWe.addTextChangedListener(null);
                scoreYou.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        int scoreY;
                        try {
                            scoreY = Integer.parseInt(scoreYou.getText().toString());
                        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                            scoreY = 0;
                        }
                        int scoreW = 200 - scoreY;
                        String scW = Integer.toString(scoreW);
                        scoreWe.setText(scW);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Those are 2 OnFocusChangeListeners, and after I try to input something in any of the EditTexts, app crashes instantly.
Log:

```
09-18 16:50:22.362 17764-17764/com.example.dvido.bela E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: com.example.dvido.bela, PID: 17764
                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void android.text.TextWatcher.beforeTextChanged(java.lang.CharSequence, int, int, int)' on a null object reference
                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.sendBeforeTextChanged(TextView.java:7941)
                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4242)
                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4199)
                                                                        at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:84)
                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4174)
                                                                        at com.example.dvido.bela.InputGame$1$1.afterTextChanged(InputGame.java:89)
                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:8007)
                                                                        at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:10168)
                                                                        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendAfterTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1043)
                                                                        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:560)
                                                                        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:492)
                                                                        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:491)
                                                                        at android.text.method.NumberKeyListener.onKeyDown(NumberKeyListener.java:121)
                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:6098)
                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:5911)
                                                                        at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2640)
                                                                        at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:9234)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2395)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1727)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2725)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:543)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:53)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:312)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2310)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4127)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4089)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3787)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3844)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3820)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3981)
                                                                        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2253)
                                                                        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1874)
```

09-18 16:50:36.917 17764-17764/com.example.dvido.bela I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 17764 SIG: 9

Comment: what does your logcat say when your main thread/app is blocked?

Comment: what do you mean by blocked? Application not responding? or Crashed?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is due to the text changed listeners are getting called on both edittext views at same time.

Try disabling the `Text changed listener` of ET1 on focus of ET2 and vice-versa. Do something like this

> Disable scoreWe textChanged Listener

```
scoreYou.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (v.hasFocus()) {
             scoreWe.addTextChangedListener(null); // ADD THIS LINE
             scoreYou.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){}); // Add and Implement this line also
             //do rest of your logic
        }
    }
});
```

> Disable scoreYou textChanged Listener

```
scoreWe.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (v.hasFocus()) {
             scoreYou.addTextChangedListener(null); // ADD THIS LINE
             scoreYou.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){}); // Add and Implement this line also
             //do rest of your logic
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It's working, but only for the first time. If I move cursor to ET2 and then back to ET1, text won't change because listener is disabled, so I have to set it back on.

Comment: @Coelacanth I have added code. Please check the updated answer. After setting other listeners to null you have to reset your listeners again. That would do the work. Try and let me know.

Comment: I've changed my code, but still nothing. I've added it above. Thank you for your help.